# How to select DISTINCT rows in mySQL DB using NodeJs ORM module?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, orm

I am using orm2 module of NodeJs for my DB works but i am stuck at the place where i need to select distinct rows from MYSQL.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [pull request](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/issues/123), you can do:

```
Person.aggregate().distinct('country').get(function (err, countries) {
    // countries should be an Array like [ 'country1', 'country2', ... ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks it is working but it is showing that cannot create ALIAS of undefined and when i removed .as() it is working fine otherwise it is giving column with name distinct_country